# Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found: - classpath:db / migrations

Tags: spring-boot, flyway, rest

I have the below configurations in my *application.properties* and attached image is the classpath.

[image].

What I am missing?

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

# Flyway
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.check-location=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migrations
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

Comment: Remove the `spirng.flyway.locations` property (it is the default, which you mangled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Flyway docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#naming) use a **capital** `V` for prefixing versioned migrations. Try to rename your migration from `v1_1__init.sql` to `V1_1__init.sql`.

Comment: SQL State  : S0001
Error Code : 2714
Message    : There is already an object named 'public' in the database.

Comment: That seems to be an error within your migration, not with your Flyway configuration. Did you ensure that the database is empty before applying the first migration?